# How to use the values calculated in ServiceNow Notification activity script inside the message body?

Tags: servicenow

I wish to create notification message which needs to have the name of the recipient and some other values calculated in the notification activity script in a workflow. How do I use them inside the message body?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, would it make sense to just create an event where you include the values you need into one of the parameters? Then in the notification you can access the parameters and parse the values in anyway you want.

Something like:

```
var jsonstr = '[{'name' : 'value'}, {'name' : 'value2'}, {'name' : 'value3'}]';
gs.eventQueue('my.event.example', current, jsonstr, '');
```

Just make sure that the parameter is a string. You can create a JSON, convert that into a string and then parse that in your email script.